# How to figure out why the JUnit test case is failing?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have to modify my class so that it passes JUnit test cases. It seems like everything should be working fine but it keeps failing. It is giving me a java.lang.AssertionError.

Here is my class

```
package dayofweek;
/**
 * Method to find out what day of the week a certain date was
 * 
 * Output determines what day of the week this certain date was
 *
 */
public class DayOfWeek {
    private int myMonth = -1, myDayOfMonth = -1, myYear= -1, myAdjustment= -1, numericDayOfWeek= -1, remainderSeven= -1;
    private static final int NO_VALUE = -1;
    /**
     * @param what the date was
     */
    public DayOfWeek(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
        myMonth = month;
        myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
        myYear = year;
        remainderSeven = 0;
        if(myMonth==1){
            myAdjustment = 1;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment=0;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==2){
            myAdjustment = 4;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment=3;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==3){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==4){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==5){
            myAdjustment = 2;
        }
        if(myMonth==6){
            myAdjustment = 5;
        }
        if(myMonth==7){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==8){
            myAdjustment = 3;
        }
        if(myMonth==9){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        if(myMonth==10){
            myAdjustment = 1;
        }
        if(myMonth==11){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==12){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        int fourDivides = myYear / 4;
        numericDayOfWeek = myAdjustment + myDayOfMonth + (myYear-1900) + fourDivides; 
        remainderSeven = numericDayOfWeek % 7;
    }
     /**
      * @return the month in a string
      */
     public String getMonthString(){
         String[] arrayOfMonths = new String[12];
         arrayOfMonths[0] = "January";
         arrayOfMonths[1] = "February";
         arrayOfMonths[2] = "March";
         arrayOfMonths[3] = "April";
         arrayOfMonths[4] = "May";
         arrayOfMonths[5] = "June";
         arrayOfMonths[6] = "July";
         arrayOfMonths[7] = "August";
         arrayOfMonths[8] = "September";
         arrayOfMonths[9] = "October";
         arrayOfMonths[10] = "November";
         arrayOfMonths[11] = "December";
         if (this.myMonth > 0 && this.myMonth <=12){
             return arrayOfMonths[this.myMonth-1];
         }
         else{
             return null;
         }
     }
     /**
      * @return what day of the month it was
      */
     public int getDayOfMonth(){
         if(myDayOfMonth != NO_VALUE){
         return myDayOfMonth;
     }
         else{
             return NO_VALUE;
         }
     }
     /**
      * @return what year it was
      */
     public int getYear(){
         if(myYear != NO_VALUE){
             return myYear;
         }
         else{
             return NO_VALUE;
         }
     }
     /**
         * @return the numeric day of the week
         */
    public int getNumericDayOfWeek(){

        return remainderSeven;

    }

    /**
     * returns what day of the week it was
     */
    public String getDayOfWeek(){   
        String[] arrayOfDays = new String[7];
        arrayOfDays[0] = "Saturday";
        arrayOfDays[1] = "Sunday";
        arrayOfDays[2] = "Monday";
        arrayOfDays[3] = "Tuesday";
        arrayOfDays[4] = "Wednesday";
        arrayOfDays[5] = "Thursday";
        arrayOfDays[6] = "Friday";
        if( myMonth != NO_VALUE && myDayOfMonth != NO_VALUE && myYear != NO_VALUE){
            return arrayOfDays[remainderSeven];
        }

         else{
             return null;
         }
     }




     /**
      * @return the month in an int
      */
     public int getMonth(){
        if(myMonth != NO_VALUE){
            return myMonth;
        }
        else return NO_VALUE;
     }




}
```

Here is the JUnit test class

```
package dayofweektesting;

import dayofweek.DayOfWeek;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Test cases for "Day of week" lab assuming requirements set 
 * at top of DayOfWeek class
 * 
 * Test valid leap years
 * 
 *
 */
public class TestValidLeapYears {

    /**
     * Test valid 2/29/XXXX dates
     */
    @Test
    public void firstValidLeapYear() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1904);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Monday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondValidLeapYear() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1908);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Saturday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void thirdValidLeapYear() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1912);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Thursday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 5);
    }

    @Test
    public void fourthValidLeapYear() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1916);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Tuesday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 3);
    }

    /**
     * Test boundary dates of2/28/XXXX and 3/1/XXXX for valid leap years
     */
    @Test
    public void firstValidLeapYearBoundaries() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 28, 1904);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Sunday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 1);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(3, 1, 1904);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Tuesday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondValidLeapYearBoundaries() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 28, 1908);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Friday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 6);
        dow = new DayOfWeek(3, 1, 1908);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Sunday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 1);
    }

}
```

Here is the line the error is pointing to, in the secondValidLeapYearBoundaries()

```
assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Friday") == 0);
```

does anyone know how to fix all these problems?

Comment: I'm assuming this is just a sockpuppet account for [Werg Asdfwer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2280266/werg-asdfwer), as this is identical to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818181/java-class-failing-a-lot-of-junit-tests-not-sure-why#comment27756374_18818181.  Please don't do that.

Comment: [This question sure seems familiar to me...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18818181/1079354)

Comment: Well I need to know if anyone knows what is going wrong. Im not a troll or anything....

Comment: @BobMarley You need to learn how to use StackOverflow properly. Read the comments you have received on other questions. Read the FAQ. Don't create duplicate accounts. Improve your question and you will get help. (Please edit one of the existing questions, **do not** create another one).

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because you have already posted the same question, two times (at least).

Comment: But if i just edit an old question then no one will see it....

Answer (score 2):

How to fix it? Print out the return value of `dow.getDayOfWeek()` for your failing case (or examine it in a debugger) to see what it *is* giving you, then single-stepping through the function to find out *why.* In this particular case, it's probably the constructor rather than `getDayOfWeek` since the latter is simply giving you information calculated by the former.

That's how you solve almost *any* problem, in coding and most other fields that are deterministic. Confirm that there's a problem then reexamine the steps to see where the problem was introduced.

Comment: Adding to this: you can use an overload. `assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Friday") == 0, "Week value:\t" + dow.getDayOfWeek());`

Comment: I try to add the System.out.print(dow.getDayOfWeek()); but nothing shows up when i run it. I have put that line in every test function

Comment: @BobMarley: Tests will not show any output. Use the method I showed in my comment, or use a debugger (place a breakpoint at the correct place, launch your tests in debug mode and check the values).

Comment: So do I replace something with what you gave me?

Comment: It's very easy: every assertation has an overload which takes a string value as additional argument. When the test fails, this string argument will be displayed next to the failure information. Format this parameter so that it displays all the info you need (e.g. the variable's value).